# JSF : How to save files so that when user logs back in again, he can see uploaded files?

Tags: java, jsf, architecture, file-upload

I am using `icefaces, ace:fileEntry` component for uploading files from client and those files are being saved in `file system`, also I have my `managedBean` marked as `sessionScope` and it make sense that when user logs out and then log in back, he/she will not see their uploaded files.

I want to do two things:

1. When user uploads file then I want to save that file to database also along with user Id or user session information.
2. When user logs out and logs back in again then he/she should be able to see his/her uploaded files, currently files are not saved after user logs out?
3. User can only see his or her uploaded files and not any random files.

My approach:

I am thinking of creating new table in database with file id, user id and file and so when file gets uploaded from client using `ace fileEntry` component then via my Hibernate, I would save file and user related information that I get from session to database, now when user logs out and logins back, I make query to database table with userId to get all his or her files.

Any thoughts or better suggestions for implementing this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate subfolder for every user based on user ID.

```
/var/webapp/uploads/[userid]
```

You can use [`File#mkdir()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29) to create a subfolder if necessary.

```
File uploads = new File("/var/webapp/uploads");
File userUploads = new File(uploads, String.valueOf(user.getId()));
userUploads.mkdir();
// ...
```

Then to get all uploaded files afterwards, just do

```
File[] allUserUploads = userUploads.listFiles();
// ...
```

This way you don't need another DB table and the users will always only see their own files.

Comment: I have 100's of user and so would there not be lot of overhead by creating one folder for each user?

Comment: The overhead is absolutely not more than using a DB table :)

Comment: Just open the subfolder matching the user ID? Didn't you understand the point of my answer?

Comment: At first glance, I didn't but now I get it, i was still thinking along the terms of getting it to database, comparing both approaches which approach will have less performance hit and why?

Comment: The filesystem is basically already a database for files. Storing files in a SQL database is often frowned upon as "poor practice" because it's not possible to search in files by SQL. You'd basically add extra columns containing the information which a simple filesystem already supports. On the other hand, storing files in a DB instead of filesystem is better portable. But the extra effort is relatively minor.

Comment: hmm...ok, i was under the impression that saving in database is always better approach then storing in filesystem, do not have much basis to support this.

Comment: Please note that files are binary data. Saving binary data in a DB makes little sense. But for real world character data (e.g. users with name, email, password, birthdate, etc) it makes fully sense to save them in a DB.

Comment: yes, my file is real world data with names, email and so i guess will go with DB saving approach

Comment: Uh, I didn't mean that :) Saving files in DB makes little sense. The filesystem is faster and better suited to storing files. The DB is better suited for storing real world data. With real world data I mean whatever data which you also have in your model objects (JPA entities, DTOs, etc), such as `User`, `Product`, `Order`, etc. They all contain character based data which you can easily select using the SQL language. For the database, files are just large and dead blobs.